# array of strings into a binary file

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, binary

I have been trying to figure out a way to store this array of strings into a binary file, but when I read it I keep getting a "Error reading characters of string" in the debug locals. If you could just take a look at my read and write operations and tell me if I am doing it right.

```
    /*Write Operation
    string bufferArray[100];
    /* Buffer array will contain strings of diffrent sizes */
    ifstream fileBack;
    fileBack.open("Backup.dat", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    fileBack.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bufferArray), sizeof(bufferArray));
    fileBack.close();

           /* Read Operation */
   ifstream fileBack;
   fileBack.open("Backup.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
   if (fileBack)
    {

        while(!fileBack.eof())
        {

            string bufferArray[100];
            fileBack.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bufferArray), sizeof(bufferArray));
        }
    fileBack.close();
    }
```

Thank you, I appreciate it

Edit: I cannot use serialization libraries such as boost, this part of a project for a class

Comment: You should know &bufferArray is the memory address of the variable, but not the content of the characters.

Comment: Fyi, `std::string` objects are NOT just something you dump by-address to an output stream like that. They're complex objects and have no business being in a stream `write` or `read` invoke as you are doing.

Comment: I'm learning that as I go through this, would converting the strings into a char array be a good way to approach this?